# react native map marker with image not anchored to coordinate

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to add a marker with a custom image, but when I zoom the marker does not stay at the original coordinate. A coordinate in Texas appears in Oklahoma when I zoom out all the way, but when I get rid of the image, the marker is anchored and stays in the same position when I zoom out.

Issue:

`<MapView.Marker coordinate={{latitude: 42.29384, longitude: 19.94830}} tracksViewChanges={false} image={require('../assets/customMarker')} />`

Not an issue:

`<MapView.Marker coordinate={{latitude: 42.29384, longitude: 19.94830}} tracksViewChanges={false} />`

Answer (score 0):

Is the marker a .png file? Have you tried renaming the marker "customMarker.png" and referencing it like so:

```js
<MapView.Marker coordinate={{latitude: 42.29384, longitude: 19.94830}} tracksViewChanges={false} image={require('../assets/customMarker.png')} />
```

Answer (score 0):

So I replaced the image with the same image but without a drop shadow and it worked.

Comment: Ah. Drop shadows can get a little funky in React Native. You might want to look at using a library like react-native-shadow https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow